# Add a parameter to the query string of all URLs loaded in a WKWebView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, query-string, wkwebview

I'm using the "new" `WKWebView` to view a site in it, say `http://mywebsite.com`.

I would make sure that the app will pass an additional parameter in each page loaded, e.g.: `http://mywebsite.com/?username=foo`.

Obviously for the first page I have no problems. In Swift:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://mywebsite.com/?username=foo")!
let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
```

But if the home page `http://mywebsite.com` there is a link, say `http://mywebsite.com/page.php?id=5`, how can I intercept it to add the parameter `username=foo`? I wish it was open page `http://mywebsite.com/page.php?id=5&username=foo`.